# Multiple unnecessary input appearing when using try except handling for input params

Tags: python

```
def input_params():
    user_input = int(input("Input a number"))
    while user_input != 1 or user_input != 2:
        try:
            user_input = int(input("Input a number"))
            if user_input == 1 or user_input == 2:
                return user_input
            else:
                print("Invalid Input")
                input_params()
        except ValueError: 
            input_params()
```

When entering an invalid input such as "adf", and then proceeding to enter a valid input such as 2, the program doesn't process the valid input and asks me to input a value again. The program only comes to process the valid input on the second time I input it.

Comment: as an aside this is a very confusing way to write this particular bit of logic: the control flow is all over the place, and the recursion doesn't really add anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use recursion. This code works just fine:

```py
def inputParams(x,y):
    while True:
        try:
            x = int(input(y))
            if x == 1 or x == 2:
                return x
            else:
                print("Invalid Input")
        except:
            pass
```

If you want to use recursion, delete the while loop, or use `return inputParams(x, y)` rather than just `inputParams(x, y)` to exit the function:

```py
def inputParams(x,y):
    try:
        x = int(input(y))
        if x == 1 or x == 2:
            return x
        else:
            print("Invalid Input")
            return inputParams(x, y)
    except:
        return inputParams(x, y)
```

Comment: This doesn't deal with the long-winded way of writing `while True`.

Comment: Um, i actually did write while true before, but removed that cause i thought it was messing up my code

Comment: @TheThonnu There's no reason for your while loop in the recursive form: the recursion gives you the loop (at cost as python has no tail-call optimisation)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're seeing comes from your test.  Let's isolate it:

```py
def f(x):
    return x != 1 or x != 2
```

Presumably this should return `True` if x is not 1 or 2.  Let's try it:

```py
def test():
    assert f(0)
    assert not f(1)
    assert not f(2)
    assert f(3)

test() # oops!
```

Take another look at that test: `x != 1` evaluates to `True` unless x is 1.  `x != 2` evaluates to `True` unless x is 2.  If `x` is 2, the first test is True.  If `x` is 1, the second test is True.  Thus the code is *actually* running:

```py
while True: ...
```

Then later on you check whether `x` is 1 or 2.  A better test would be `if x in {1, 2}` or even `if 1 <= x <= 2`.

Then your recursion is muddling things even further, but you don't actually need recursion for this problem.

Comment: Ok, I understand what I did wrong, thanks